# Delete record 36 hours after insert in postgres using Triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I've stored some PDF exports in the repository which are generated by the scheduler. After 36 hours I need to delete those PDF's.

Table1
id(pk of table2), file_type, data

table2
id, name, label, created_date, updated_date

Now how can I write a trigger which can delete the records from **Table1** and **Table2** after 36 hours.

I've written this but It is executing only when an Insert is done. I wanted it to run even when none of the even is occured.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ContentResource_Delete() RETURNS trigger AS $ContentResource_Delete$

BEGIN
    delete from jicontentresource jicr USING  jiresource jir 
    where jicr.id = jir.id and jicr.file_type='pdf' and trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - creation_date)/3600) >=1 ;
    delete from jiresource where name like '%.pdf' and trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - creation_date)/3600) >=1 ;   
    RETURN NULL;
END;$ContentResource_Delete$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ContentResource_Delete AFTER INSERT ON jiresource FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ContentResource_Delete();
```

Comment: You'll have fewer problems with an hourly batch job that deletes old entries, rather than a trigger on insert. With your trigger, if there are no insertions, your database doesn't get the maintenance it requires, and if for any reason deletes fail, your insert will either fail (if you don't handle exceptions) or slow down considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I got the solution, instead of using triggers I've used pgAgent and configured. 
 If anyone facing issues while scheduling apart from default database (i.e. postgres) then in the step,**ConnectionType** should be **Remote**, connection string should be **IP Address** instead of **localhost** , specify the **password** and  provide the **databasename**. Refer the Image

[image]